# It was... at the market conference

Tags: grammar

It was ____ at the market conference.

A. Her
B. Him
C. Them
D. She

Comment: There is no way to tell. All can be considered OK.

Comment: @Lambie If the lesson is on pronouns with the verb to be, there is one answer.  All are acceptable but the subject pronoun is "grammatically correct," whatever that means.

Comment: Can we see the instructions for this question please?

Comment: I don't think "she" can fit this sentence, but any of the others could, unless there is added context,

Comment: @DavidSiegel the "correct" answer is most likely "she", because technically a subject pronoun belongs there, as livresque said. Assuming this question is reasonable, you can determine the answer without that, precisely because the others are equivalent without context. Although, these kinds of questions are not always reasonable ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Esther Perhaps I am mistaken, but it seems to me that the missing word would be the **object** of "was" and so should be in the objective case, making "she" the only clearly **wrong** answer. Certainly "*It was **her***." is correct, while  "*It was **she***." is not correct.

Comment: @DavidSiegel https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298253/it-was-he-it-was-him

Comment: @Esther I have now read through that thread and the linked thread. I had not known of the special rule for "to be" before, and I am inclined to agree with those who call it a zombie rule not now having any effect on actual usage, and possibly never having done so. But it might be that rule the question was trying to teach.